# RCTBatchedBridge.m Error: Invalid data message - all must be length:%zd. React Native, iOS simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth, react-native, bridge

I'm using `react-native-oauth` and getting this error (see red image at bottom) when trying to authorise. I've searched and found only this [similar unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905638/error-invalid-data-message-all-must-be-length-8-pickerios). I looked into the source and found [where the error is raised](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Base/RCTBatchedBridge.m) on line 954 and it seems it's because `moduleIDs.count` should equal `methodIDs.count` and `paramsArrays.count` :

```
  if (RCT_DEBUG && (moduleIDs.count != methodIDs.count || moduleIDs.count != paramsArrays.count)) {
RCTLogError(@"Invalid data message - all must be length: %zd", moduleIDs.count);
```

So, still in [the source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Base/RCTBatchedBridge.m), I look for these objects and find them defined just above, on lines 943-945 and they are using RCTConvert, whose functions "...all accept a JSON value as input and map it to a native Objective-C type or class." [- React's docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html)

So it seems like this is a transpiling and/or networking related error. But I have basically 0 knowledge on those fields and feel I've hit a barrier to investigating and wondered if anybody had any ideas on moving forward. Being new to React Native and never having done any Objective-C can't be helping me.

Also, here's my code generating the errors.

```
import OAuthManager from 'react-native-oauth';
import {
Alert
} from 'react-native'
var env = require('../environment.js')
const config =  {
  facebook: {
    client_id: env.getKey("FB_ID"),
    client_Secret: env.getKey("FB_SECRET")
  }
}
const manager = new OAuthManager('myAppName')
manager.configure(config);
exports.authWithFb = () => {
   manager.authorize('facebook')
     .then(resp => Alert.alert('response!' + resp))
     .catch(err => Alert.alert('error msg here: ' + err));
}
```

I am guessing this undefined error is related to the RCTBridge error but not sure. You can below see when I Alert the `manager.authorize`'s caught error. `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'fn')`:

[image][image: this error]

Edit:

When I try to Alert the `config` object, I get an error about not being able to stringify it's sub-object. [image]

When looking in console in chrome debugger, I get "Cannot read property 'configureProvider' of undefined" and `configureProvider()` is what `react-native-oauth` uses so it looks like the manager is not set up right so maybe I didn't link the library well. Have checked the linking worked.

Im digging into the errors a bit and it seems like a promise/callback related problem from `NativeModules.OAuthManager`. The error caught is: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'authorize' of undefined`. When I jump into the stack trace I find: [image]

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So for me whatever was going wrong was a setup issue with `react-native-oauth` because everything has fixed itself since I've rolled back to a point where my code had no other dependencies (I also had Firestack installed) and set up from scratch again following react-native-oauth's docs. I realised that there was a step on iOS/XCode's side that I had missed out because when I originally tried I couldn't find the file so just skipped that step:

From [react-native-oauth readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-oauth)

> Next, navigate to the neighboring "Build Phases" section of project settings, find the "Link Binary with Library" drop down, expand it, and click the "+" to add libOAuthManager.a to the list.

The errors I were getting were a few steps removed from this but I'm sure connected somehow. Lessons learnt: don't try to do too many things at once and don't skip required steps.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get this error when you will send some wrong data into native side. For example if you should pass string but you passed an object.

Please console.log your `config` variable.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-oauth

I guess you're sent some wrong data into native side

Comment: Also please make sure that you linked library properly